# Resolving Tree Conflicts in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

Here's the scenario:

I created a folder with the name "01.07.T1" in local with some content in it and updated it on Tortoise SVN, and a friend of mine created a folder in his local with the name "01.07.t1" with the same content and also updated that on tortoise SVN..
now it apparently was a tree conflict in SVN, but in order to resolve that, unknowingly, i deleted the folder with me (i.e. the 01.07.T1 one) and took an SVN update, after which I committed the files.. this has now led to a new conflict when one of the files has been deleted and SVN, being case-insensitive, is not giving an update of those files on other devices..
Someone please suggest necessary steps to resolve the tree conflict..

Thankyou in advance..

Answer (score 0):

say parent directory of 01.07.T1 is p

say p's url in repo is http://svn.repo/project/p

steps:

```
svn export http://svn.repo/project/p my_folder
```

(If 01.07.T1 has been already deleted from repository then you should do: `svn export http://svn.repo/project/p my_folder -r567`  ... being 567 the latest revision in which 01.07.T1 existed and you liked it (you can check by looking at revision history through tortoise or either by command line: `svn log -v http://svn.repo/project/p | less`)

```
svn del http://svn.repo/project/p
```

... delete 01.07.T1 folder from my_folder if both 01.07.t1 and 01.07.T1 exist

```
svn import my_folder http://svn.repo/project/p
```

... finally, delete your p directory from any corrupted local copy and do `svn up`

Comment: would this work even if the file has been marked as deleted from SVN? as both the files are with the same name.. and 01.07.T1 has already been updated on SVN as deleted?

Comment: I've improved my answer accordingly.

Comment: so i guess it will revert back to the state when it was like, both the files existed.. will that lead to losing any data that is committed after that instance?

Comment: yes, if new data have been commited to that same directory. If to other directories, no problem. If you have other new files after revision 567 (in my example), then get them with `svn export http://svn.repo/project/p last_revision_of_p` ... later move them to my_folder, and then do the import